# Simple view to Split view ios programming

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I want to know if it is possible to have a first view that acts as a menu (that has a couple of buttons for which one is Edit). I want to be able when I click on edit to then show a split view. Now, when I do that, I get the error :

Application tried to present a Split View Controllers modally

My code in the action method of the edit button is :

```
UIStoryboard *editorStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"EditorStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *editorViewController = [editorStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];

editorViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:editorViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

So I am assuming, the `ViewController` that contains the button is the root VC. You should change that with the `SplitVC` when tapping the button (add a nice animation), because the split should be the root of your app (it should not be presented modally). Hope this helps!

**Edit:**

It should look something like:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
appDelegate.window.rootViewContrller = mySplitViewController;
```

You can also do this in your custom segue if you have one.

Comment: Alright, so if I try to do that, it doesn't work. I am clearly missing something out...    
http://pastebin.com/BkE9187c

Comment: That's what I pasted in the pastebin link... strange that it doesn't work